# C++ use selectionSort algorithm on an array of object pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, pointers

I am trying to utilize the selection sort algorithm to sort an array of object pointers on an int that is a member variable of each object.  The getter function is getVar() and works properly.  Obviously, what I have here won't work, as I end up trying to swap an int with an object pointer.  I sure I'm missing something along the lines of declaring and using anObject* = temp, but I'm just not grasping it. (I see several somewhat similar questions on this topic, but none are quite like this.) Thank you.

```
void selectSort(anObject* array[], int size) {
int i;
int minIdx;
int minVal;

for (i = 0; i < (size - 1); i++) {
    minIdx = i;
    minVal = array[i]->getVar();
    for (int index = i + 1; index < size; index++) {
        if (array[index]->getVar() < minVal) {
            minVal = array[index]->getVar();
            minIdx = index;
        }
    }
    array[minIdx] = array[i];
    array[i] = minVal; // invalid conversion from int to *anObject
}
```

}

Comment: You should swap the elements at i and minIdx ( using a temp ). Do you have a setValue() member function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fix.  You can also use std::swap() if you're in C++.

```
void selectSort(anObject* array[], int size) {
    int i;
    int minIdx;
    int minVal;
    anObject *temp;

    for (i = 0; i < (size - 1); i++) {
        minIdx = i;
        minVal = array[i]->getVar();
        for (int index = i + 1; index < size; index++) {
            if (array[index]->getVar() < minVal) {
                minVal = array[index]->getVar();
                minIdx = index;
            }
        }
        temp = array[minIdx]
        array[minIdx] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got the bubble sort version working, but this one is more efficient!